# Identify if a text was sent using an iPhone

Tags: ios, messages

How can I find out if a text was sent via an iPhone instead of a Mac? I want to see if my kids are texting me from their iPhones or iPads to make sure they are where they say they are.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it can't be done.

One option might be [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060), which would give you access to 'find my device' on everybody's devices.

Answer (score 1):

I believe  Tetsujin is correct, however there might be a helpful hint.

When you send an SMS from one iPhone to anything but another iPhone the text bubble will be green. If you send an SMS to someone with an iPhone (or iPad) it will go via iMessage and show up as blue.

Now the iPad can't send or recieve SMS messages but the iPhone can.

iMessages are associated with an AppleID (@icloud.com email address). So a clever person might make sure that a child'd iPhone does not have an associated AppleID set up in Messages (ensuring only SMS and location tracking via find my iPhone) and one set up on the iPad only.

Then when you send an SMS from your phone it will show up as green or blue depending on where it goes to allowing you to infer which defice is active by which messages they respond to?

That sounds a bit kludgey, so anyone with a better idea is welcome to add on...

Comment: My guess is the OP meant iDevice vs fixed location compy - ie, leave the compy at a friend's to map 'legal' location, then go somewhere else & message from phone/pad, spoofing the location. What you need is to be able to overlay the location of both compy & phone & make sure they agree.

Comment: Wrong: "Now the iPad can't send or recieve SMS messages... "